# How do I know which version of SQL Server my bacpac is for? (I'm using SQL Server 2019 express on Ubuntu )

Tags: sql, sql-server, ubuntu

I was given a SQL Server bacpac file to restore a database on a Ubuntu 20.x instance.

I thought I would use this command to restore the file:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P "Password123!" -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [demodb] FROM DISK = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/mssql-latest.bacpac' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS = 5"
```

Though the error it fed me was:

> Msg 3241, Level 16, State 1, Server 6f604ce9f741, Line 1
> The media family on device '/var/opt/mssql/backup/mssql-latest.bacpac' is incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server 6f604ce9f741, Line 1
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

And when looking into this more via google searches it seems to be related to an older version of SQL Server bacpac being used with a newer version of SQL Server.

I am currently running SQL Server 2019 Express, thinking that this would work.

How can I find out which version I need to use without downloading every version of SQL Server?  Similarly, How do I know if I need to use Express or Developer, or any of the other versions of SQL Server.  I thought Express would be ideal because I think it is lightweight.

Comment: This error occurs when trying to restore newer version to older version. Most probably, the BACPAC is from Azure SQL. Express is enough for smaller workloads. Developer and Enterprise editions are same. So, developer is having all the enterprise features. Express will have limited set of features. You can easily upgrade from developer to enterprise in future, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real issue here is, you are trying to restore a .BACPAC file using "RESTORE DATABASE" command which will obviously fail as "RESTORE DATABASE" command is used to restore .BAK file not .BACPAC file.

You got to use SQLPackage utility to restore a BACPAC file. Details are provided [here](https://www.techsupportpk.com/2016/11/how-to-migrate-databases-to-sql-server-on-red-hat-or-ubuntu-linux.html).

Comment: That makes sense.  I was not sure what explicitly a bacpac file was, as it seemed that it was just a DB to restore, but i guess there is more to it if it is exported as a BAK vs bacpac.  Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 2):

BACPAC is basically ZIP file. You can change the extension of file to zip file and extract it. You can see the version of the SQL Server.

[Reference article on editing bacpac file](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/editing-a-bacpac-file/ba-p/368931)

[image: BACPAC Extracted Folder]

You can open the Origin.xml for the SQL Server version of the BACPAC.

[image: SQL Server version]

Also, to answer your question of SQL Server Express Vs SQL Server Developer. SQL Server Express is limited feature set and SQL Server Developer is with full feature set as SQL Server Enterprise edition. But, you can use SQL Server Developer only for the development purposes and not in production. Express edition is having some limitation on storage and features. If it is not satisfying, you can go for Developer edition and later upgrade, when you go for production.

[The different editions of SQL Server and differences among them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: So it seems that a bacpac file is unique and an alternative way to storing a database than a standard bak file?   So, I would need to use SqlPackage to manage imports?